# What is the exact meaning of '能虐到我的只有没钱'?

Tags: meaning

I found this [meme](https://fabiaoqing.com/biaoqing/detail/id/352537.html) (?) on a group, and I'm not sure what is the exact meaning of this. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

虐 means "torture"

In combat game lingo 完虐 (complete torture) means "defeat someone in a completely dominating fashion that it is not even a fight but a one sided torture"

The usage of 完虐 has extended outside of gaming field. It can be used in any field of competition, or simply describe " dominating"

能虐到我的 - the thing that can defeat me like a one sided torture

只有没钱 - is only poverty

*He is not afraid of anything, but afraid of being poor very much*

Answer (score 2):

the only thing can defeat me is poverty